# Why won't this python 3 for loop work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to get an output that says:

```
We won in *year x*!!

All about the U!!
```

I want this to repeat for each year in the list, so the output would be:

```
We won in 1983!!

All about the U!!

We won in 1987!!

All about the U!!

ect. repeat for each year.
```

What I keep on getting is:

```
We won in [1983, 1987, 1989, 1991, 2001]!!

All about the U!!

*repeated for the length of the list, 5 times*
```

### Below is the code I tried:

```
yearlist = [1983, 1987, 1989, 1991, 2001]

for wewon in yearlist:
    print("We won in {}!!".format(yearlist))
    print("All about the U!!")
```

where did I go wrong?

Comment: `format(wewon)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the loop variable (`wewon`), not the list (`yearlist`):

```
print("We won in {}!!".format(wewon))
```

`wewon` will take on each value of `yearlist`.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

✓ **@John**, try the below code:

> In each iteration you will get item of list assigned to **wewon** which is an year, so don't use list in print() function
>
> You can try the below code at http://rextester.com/GDIT18485

```
yearlist = [1983, 1987, 1989, 1991, 2001]

for wewon in yearlist:
    print("We won in {}!!".format(wewon))
    print("All about the U!!")
```

✓ Output:

```
We won in 1983!!
All about the U!!
We won in 1987!!
All about the U!!
We won in 1989!!
All about the U!!
We won in 1991!!
All about the U!!
We won in 2001!!
All about the U!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Both good solutions but I just have an unnatural fondness for iterables...

```
In [65]: yr = (i for i in ('1983', '1987', '1989', '1991', '2001'))    

In [66]: type(yr)    
Out[66]: generator    

In [67]: while True:    
    ...:     try:    
    ...:         print(f'We won in {next(yr)}!!\nAll about the U!!')    
    ...:     except StopIteration:    
    ...:         pass    
    ...:         break
```

Output:
We won in 1983!!
All about the U!!
We won in 1987!!
All about the U!!
We won in 1989!!
All about the U!!
We won in 1991!!
All about the U!!
We won in 2001!!
All about the U!!